# Krunner not working on Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, debian, kde, stretch

I have just installed Debian Stretch with KDE.

When I press ALT+F2 to invoke Krunner I would just get a little white pixel on the top of the screen /the focus will go to this pixel/.

I have tried to type konsole and press enter but it does not do anything (other that the white dot would dissapear).

If I run krunner from terminal directly I have following:

```
bruno@Casper:~$ krunner
 "file:///usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/runcommand/RunCommand.qml" 
 "Error loading QML file.\n132: Type Milou.ResultsView unavailable\n79:    Type ResultDelegate unavailable\n144: Cannot assign to non-existent    property \"separatorVisible\"\n"
```

I have checked and the file exists. Can't comment on correctness of the contents though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade system. Had the same problem before today's upgrade of packages.

Comment: That indeed fixed it